# java fx ui stuck on button event

Tags: java, events, javafx

On button click I add a new fxml to borderpane center:

```
 @FXML Pane MainGUICenter;
```

But on button click my button stuck, and I am unaable to press it again.
It changes the view but the button is then stuck, preventing me from doing other action.

```
@FXML
private void LadeCenterNeu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
          MainGUICenter.getChildren().clear();
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    MainGUICenter.getChildren().add((Node)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Views/Center.fxml")));
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                }
            }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Plase create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The thing I notice right away is that you are doing a "Platform.runLater," on the GUI thread, when there is no point in doing so, which is probably why there is an issue.  Can you try removing the Platform block and the run method?